# How do I detect if a button was clicked with a keyboard key pressed? (Ctrl-click, Alt-click etc.)

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, keyboard-events, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

I'm trying to write a UI for an Adobe After Effects script. I want to add a functionality where a user can CTRL click a button instead of just clicking it with no keypresses to get a slightly different behavior.

The problem is, however, I don't to know how to detect if a key was pressed when the button was clicked.

I've managed to detect a keypress with

```
myPanel.addEventListener("keydown", function (kd) {alert(kd.keyIdentifier); return(kd.keyIdentifier);});
```

This piece of code adds a listener that alerts me a name of the button when it is being pressed. I also have a button `onClick` event to control what happens when a button is pressed. However, I can't figure out how to combine those two listeners and get an information about whether a key was pressed during the button click. I tried to place the `keydown` listener inside the `onClick` function, but then it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

The Adobe ScriptUI environment lets you monitor the keyboard status at all times using the `Keyboard state` object. You can get it from: `ScriptUI.environment.keyboardState`. It has properties such as `altKey`, `ctrlKey` and so on that return a boolean based on whether they key was pressed or not. All you have to do is put the object initiation into the `onClick` event of the button:

```
button.onClick = function() {
    isCtrlPressed = ScriptUI.environment.keyboardState.ctrlKey;
}
```

For more information, I refer to p.155 of the Adobe JavaScript Tools Guide

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="sample(event)">Click Me!</button>

function sample(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey){
       alert('Button click with ctrlKey pressing.');
    }else{
       alert('Button click without ctrlKey pressing.');
    }
}
```

Event object has some key press or not. Check that then use it.

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHIGKDWKYZVW)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in the Adobe ScriptUI environment